# Data table split value error in R

Tags: r, split, data.table

I've created a simple `data.table` based function in R that lets me insert the desired data frame and split the values with semicolon(s) in order to create additional rows where the full list expands and the entries of other columns remain unchanged.

```
splitSemicolons = function(x){
new_df <- data.table(x, key="SampleID")
final_df <- new_df[, list(Identifier = unlist(strsplit(Identifier, ";"))), by=c('SampleID', 'Name')]
}
```

My data frame

```
>df
SampleID, Name, Identifier
1, John, PS897
2, Mary, GF521
3, George, DG636;DG637
4, Helen, 
5, Patrick, WV168
```

For some reason, after executing the function the console gives me error; "object 'Identifier' not found", instead of delivering the result below. Weird thing is, the code runs perfectly outside the function brackets, but deleted completely entries with blank values like Helen in SampleID=4.

```
>desired_result
SampleID, Name, Identifier
1, John, PS897
2, Mary, GF521
3, George, DG636
3, George, DG637
4, Helen, 
5, Patrick, WV168
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `cSplit` to convert from 'wide' to 'long' format by splitting at the delimiter (`;`), and specify the `stripWhite` as 'FALSE' to ensure that blank rows are not removed.

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df, "Identifier", ";", "long", stripWhite=FALSE)
#   SampleID     Name Identifier
#1:        1     John      PS897
#2:        2     Mary      GF521
#3:        3   George      DG636
#4:        3   George      DG637
#5:        4    Helen           
#6:        5  Patrick      WV168
```

---

Or if we are using `data.table`, convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), replicate the sequence of rows by the number of `;` in each row, then do the split of the `unique` "Identifier" grouped by "SampleID" and assign (`:=`) it as "Identifier" column.

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
setDT(df)[rep(1:.N,str_count(Identifier, ";")+1)][, 
          Identifier := strsplit(unique(Identifier), ";"), SampleID][]
#   SampleID     Name Identifier
#1:        1     John      PS897
#2:        2     Mary      GF521
#3:        3   George      DG636
#4:        3   George      DG637
#5:        4    Helen           
#6:        5  Patrick      WV168
```